# How to change a word into drop down menu in text field or input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building custom spellchecker in React.js and I am stuck in changing the word into the dropdown menu to select the correct word.
Please help.

I am doing research on it from a long time but to no avail.

Comment: please post the code snippet you have tryied

Comment: @KOTIOS I've a basic text field only. I am just looking for general approach to do it.

Comment: Alright , i m actually not understood the functionality you are trying to achieve hence will you like to give any example what are you looking for?

Comment: We are building our own spell checker like Grammarly. For that when user type in the text box, If the spelling is wrong, then we will mark that word wrong(highlight it with colour or bold). and when the user hovers on that word then a drop down should be opened with word suggestions. 
so I'm able to highlight the wrong word but not able to replace word string with dropdown menu.

Comment: so there are already few control like react-autocomplete which does the same thing , try looking few examples for custom react-autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looking for a general approach, here's how I would approach this problem.

When a word is misspelled, replace it with a React component containing two children: the text displaying the misspelled word, and your 'replacement word' select box. Fill the select with possible replacement words.

Use a React Synthetic Event (`onMouseOver`?) to toggle between displaying the components-- select on mouse over, display text otherwise. I might suggest `onClick`, since I think that's easier to use and more mobile-first.

When the user selects one of the replacement words, the word is no longer evaluated as misspelled, and the entire parent component unmounts, replaced by the correctly spelled word.

[React Synthetic Events docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)